# Horizontal scroll bar appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I would like to combine two SVG on each other.
I have made a section within her a container who has a row.

The row have a class float-end and the row have two containers with each one SVG.

I changed the CSS for having a position absolute for SVG and it's work but I have a horizontal scroll bar and I tried many things but I don't find the solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16));
}

#svg2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16));

  
}

#svg2 path{
  d:path('M2032.906,316.652c-29.922,11.176-125.248,135.8-176.452-11.575s-65.814-28.162-108.034-59.206-99.488-84.638-69.539-161.431S1754.629-21.08,1754.629-21.08h278.277');
  animation: morph 5s infinite;
}

#svg2:hover path{
  d:path:hover('M2032.906,299.7c-44.543,52.9-130.008,123.125-181.212-24.248s-72.743-22.043-103.274-29.58-81.155-90.923-56.907-164.4,63.116-102.55,63.116-102.55h278.277');
}

@keyframes morph {
  0%, 100%{
    d:path('M2032.906,316.652c-29.922,11.176-125.248,135.8-176.452-11.575s-65.814-28.162-108.034-59.206-99.488-84.638-69.539-161.431S1754.629-21.08,1754.629-21.08h278.277');
  }
  50%{
    d:path('M2032.906,299.7c-44.543,52.9-130.008,123.125-181.212-24.248s-72.743-22.043-103.274-29.58-81.155-90.923-56.907-164.4,63.116-102.55,63.116-102.55h278.277')
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row float-end">
    <div class="container col-6">
      <svg id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="362.354" height="397.564" viewBox="0 0 362.354 397.564">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="1" y1="0.033" x2="0.422" y2="0.662" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#469295"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#3cd698"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path id="Tracé_6" data-name="Tracé 6" class="cls-1" d="M2032.906,316.652c-29.922,11.176-125.248,135.8-176.452-11.575s-65.814-28.162-108.034-59.206-99.488-84.638-69.539-161.431S1754.629-21.08,1754.629-21.08h278.277" transform="translate(-1670.552 21.08)"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="container col-6">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="338.882" height="372.679" viewBox="0 0 338.882 372.679">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="1" y1="0.033" x2="0.422" y2="0.662" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#469295"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#3cd698"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path id="Tracé_1" data-name="Tracé 1" d="M1999.591,275.825s-101.794,169.041-169.437,0-109.919-45.687-109.919-45.687-93.009-54.824-46.5-159.9,88.781-91.373,88.781-91.373h237.08" transform="translate(-1660.708 21.725)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `left` or `right` css property to your svgs.

e.g.

```css
#svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16));
  right: 0;
}

#svg2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16));
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't understand why I need to add a right: 0, I need to search on google for have more information about this.